Async method returning without the result
In my SpringBoot application I have a endpoint that needs to return data in an async way. The method is populating the data but when testing via postman it is returning 200 OK with blank data. I have tried the below 2 approaches but both are returning blank response. Requesting to please check and suggest.
Approach 1

@Async(value = "threadPoolTaskExecutor")
public List<Movie> getMoviesOfHeroASync() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    List<Movie> allMoviesOfHeroesList = new ArrayList<>();

    String heroes = "aaa;bbb;ccc";

    List<CompletableFuture<Map<String, List<Movie>>>> completableFutureList = Arrays.stream(heroes.split(";")).map(this::getMoviesOfHero).toList();

    CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutureList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();

    for(CompletableFuture<Map<String, List<Movie>>> completableFuture : completableFutureList){

        if(!completableFuture.get().isEmpty()) {

            completableFuture.get().values().stream().findAny().ifPresent(allMoviesOfHeroesList::addAll);
        }

    }

    return allMoviesOfHeroesList;

}

Approach 2
@Async(value = "threadPoolTaskExecutor")
public List<Movie> getMoviesOfHeroASync() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    List<Movie> allMoviesOfHeroesList = new ArrayList<>();

    String heroes = "aaa;bbb;ccc";

    List<CompletableFuture<Map<String, List<Movie>>>> completableFutureList = Arrays.stream(heroes.split(";")).map(this::getMoviesOfHero).toList();


    CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutureList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]))
            .thenApplyAsync(value -> {
                for(CompletableFuture<Map<String, List<Movie>>> completableFuture : completableFutureList){

                    try {
                        if(!completableFuture.get().isEmpty()) {

                            completableFuture.get().values().stream().findAny().ifPresent(allMoviesOfHeroesList::addAll);
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }

                }
                return null;
            });


    return allMoviesOfHeroesList;

}



Async functions do not execute immediately in the same thread, it should return a Future.  Have you tried following a tutorial? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async

Please provide reproducible example as it defined at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example At least provide Movie class, getMoviesOfHero method and a test case, better with curl

Reaolved , i had to remove the @Async from this method as it is in the main thread, the called method will run async and join here ro rhe main thread

Approach 2 won't solve your issue. Yes, the method returns immediately, but at that time the list is probably still empty because the CompletableFuture is still running, and hasn't filled it yet. Also, your code is not thread-safe because you use a non-concurrent list in concurrent code.
